# Image size is not correct

Tags: html, css

I am trying to size 3 images to be the same width divided equally on one row.The last image is full size. It is also not changing the height on it.  How come?

```css
.activity-snippets {
  display: flex;
}

.activity-post-link {
  height: 215px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity-snippets">
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not only your last image is bigger, every image is in full size... Its just that the last two divs are overlapping each other and hence you get the feeling that the image is cropped as per your given width... check inspect element on that image to see what I'm talking about...

Comment: Ends up being me misspelling one of the class names which caused the height issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make use of **`max-width: 100%`** to the **`img`** tag. Using this image will take the width of parent container

```css
.activity-snippets {
  display: flex;
}

.activity-post-link {
  height: 215px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity-snippets">
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image size it not changing it may be because you have added class in the div element not in the image.

```
<div class="activity-snippets">
  <div>
    <img class="activity-post-link" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
   </div>

  <div>
    <img class="activity-post-link" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
   </div>

  <div>
    <img  class="activity-post-link" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.activity-snippets {
  display: flex;
}

.activity-post-link {
  height: 215px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.activity-post-link img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity-snippets">
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
  <div class="activity-post-link">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
  </div>
</div>
```